# checking state to conditionally map component

Tags: reactjs

I have a map function which maps components. Within the component that the `.map` is mapping I am trying to create a render where it checks the state last mapped and if it is the same wont display it.

This is the render function of the component that is mapped (so far it is showing dates that are the same when I want it to show ones that are different)

How could I modify this so that it checks the last state that was rendered. So far I have tried saving these into a variable with no luck.

```
render() {
  console.log(
    `${this.state.previousDate} PREVIOUS DATE ${this.state.questions.Date}  DATE`
  );

  if (!(this.state.previousDate == this.state.questions.Date)) {
    if (this.state.questions.Accepted > 0) {
      this.state.previousDate = this.state.questions.Date;
      return (
        <div>
          <button
            onClick={this.checker}
            className="btn btn-primary"
            style={{ float: "right" }}
          >
            View Details
          </button>
          <h4 style={{ float: "right" }}>✔️</h4>
          <br />

          <li> {this.state.questions.Date}</li>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      this.state.previousDate = this.state.questions.Date;
      return (
        <div>
          <h4 style={{ float: "right" }}>❌</h4>
          <br />

          <li> {this.state.questions.Date}</li>
        </div>
      );
    }
  } else {
    this.state.previousDate = this.state.questions.Date;

    return <>ok...</>;
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: always use `setState` to change the state! Your code is mutating the state object

Comment: `this.state.previousDate = this.state.questions.Date` what does this do? You can't update state like this. It should be `this.setState({previousDate: this.state.questions.Date })`